# Relative inefficiency of doorless fridges at supermarkets

Tags: electrical-engineering, refrigeration

It appears to be a waste of electricity to keep a bank of refrigerators wide open with no doors or covers whatsoever on them.

They seem to be just blowing cold air out into the supermarket.

They are not turned off at night when the store closes.  Even the "green" Whole Foods-type places do this.

But is it really that inefficient to operate them that way? 
  What is the relative efficiency between a refrigerator with a door and one without a door in a supermarket?

[image: Fridge without door]

[image: Fridge with door]

Comment: Perhaps poorly worded, but a legit question. And the answer isn't completely clear as this paper describes: [Lindberg Ulla et al, 2008, Supermarkets, indoor climate and energy efficiency – field measurements before and after installation of doors on refrigerated cases.](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1878&context=iracc)

Comment: Another aspect to consider is that from personal anecdotal experience, the drinks in the open fridges just aren't as cold, even if you take one right from the back - I'd expect that they are actually burning a similar amount of energy as each other, but the open one isn't getting to such a low temperature. This fits with the way my local supermarket runs things, with raw meat, dairy, etc. behind doors, and soft drinks, sandwiches etc. where a low temperature isn't so critical in an open section.

Comment: Changing the images after people have already answered affects people's answers...

Comment: @SolarMike  The images were edited in by another contributor if you check the history. I was specifically thinking of meat displays when I asked this question, so I changed it. Overall, it's the same concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doorless models (this was the photo in the question when I answered it) aren't as inefficient as they appear to be. [image: Original photo.]

Whenever someone opens a regular fridge door, its cold air pours out onto the floor and warm air replaces it inside the fridge.  If the doors are opened frequently, or held open for significant time, there is a lot of waste.

On the other hand, the doorless models are designed to have a laminar flow of cold air from top to bottom.  Most of the cold air emitted at the top is sucked back in at the bottom, with far less mixing with the surrounding warm air than one might think.

So for products where temperature control isn't critical, and where many people are likely to take the product or to spend a long time looking and deciding, the doorless models are a good choice.

(They're also good from a marketing perspective, as they provide an excellent view of the product and don't have doors that fog up, but that's not the question.)

Comment: Hmmm, but the ones I've seen are used for meat products as well, where temperature control IS critical! See picture above.

Comment: The picture in the question changed.  The one there now is more of a bunker, than the one I was talking about.  Because cold air doesn't rise, it has a reliable temperature (and a max-height limit marked inside it).

Answer (score 0):

Most of those units as per the top image do have some type of insulating cover for the time the shops etc are closed. This is part of the closing process, and opening the next day...

The lower image shows doors, which are, in many cases now, double glazed for efficiency as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, refrigerators with door have approximately **40% higher energy efficiency** on average. Doorless refrigerators are preferred when it is required extra convenience to consumers. For this type of refrigerators, in night, automatic or manual curtain (cover etc.) applications are already available for energy-saving.

Comment: Not sure where your 40% comes from because Fricke 2010 (Energy Use of Doored and Open Vertical Refrigerated Display Cases) indicates that adding a door reduces the refrigeration load by 68% and the compressor power consumption by 87%. [Fricke](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2153&context=iracc)

Comment: The numbers you provide are valid under extreme conditions. 40% comes directly from the field and shows only the average value.